# Discord.py бот - не работает метод on_member_join

Tags: python, бот, discord

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    //код
```

Ни @bot.event, ни @client.event не работают. SERVER MEMBERS INTENT включено. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

`bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$', intents=intents)`

Answer (score 1):

Включи их на сайте discord developer во вкладке bot.
Вот ссылка на документацию: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html
[image: 1][image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

я тоже долго страдал от этой проблемы, связана она с обновлением discord API, чтобы event заработал, достаточно в начале прописать это:
(Я с телефона, так что код почему-то добавить нельзя)
intents = discord.Intents.all()

Должно получиться так:
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = discord.Intents.all())

У меня всё сразу заработало